# How to create specific role permissions for authenticated users in Drupal 7

Tags: users

I'm developing a Drupal 7 based site. As an administrator of a site I want to add some specific access permissions for authenticated users.
By default in Drupal authenticated users can read the content. And they can view the author of content. I want to disable the feature of viewing the author, but only for concrete contents. 
When an authenticated user creates content, I want to make him able to choose "creating a content as anonymous author", i.e. other users can read and comment that content, but unable to see it's author.
And additionally this feature shouldn't affect quantity of content posted by that user. When the user creates content it will be incremented in "Number of content created by this user", whether content was created as "anonymous author" or not.
I've looked up in "People > permissions" , but couldn't find a permission like that. I know a little PHP, so if the answer requires a knowledge of PHP, go ahead.

Comment: Either find a module that controls what you need, or see [Examples for Developers](https://drupal.org/project/examples) to code it yourself. Could you please edit your question for clarity, and title to make it less broad? And remember, we don't do "code from scratch" type of help here, we can help with your code, but will not code it for you.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Very helpful. I think, I will delete this question.

Comment: Edit is always preferred to deletion, and someone answered - so it must be possible to make your question clearer. Probably it's only the lack of formatting and unspecific title that makes it a problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at [User points module](https://drupal.org/project/userpoints), you also need userpoints_nodelimit, part of [User Points Contributed modules](https://drupal.org/project/userpoints_contrib) to limit the number of nodes a specific user is allowed to create. For the deletion of nodes you'll need the rules modules so you can give the user a point back.

You could write your own implementation, but depending on your skills this might be harder, in short you need to implement:

- an access callback where you check the user and the number of available points
- use hook_menu_alter to replace the access callback of 'node/add'
- implement [hook_node_delete](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_delete/7) and hook_node_isnert to change the counter

Comment: Hi there. It seems you understood OP pretty well. Could you please edit his question to introduce formatting and clarity, and to make title more specific?